# Nikon D3200 does not recognize the Nikkor AF-S 50mm 1.8G

Tags: lens, troubleshooting, nikon-d3200

I bought a new Nikkor 50mm AF-S 1.8G to add to my Nikon D3200, however, it will not recognize the lens. It says `"Lens Not Attached"` in all modes with error `"NON CPU lenses can only be used in manual mode"`. The AF-S lens is a CPU lens and compatible in all modes with D3200 (as per the spec). Even in Manual mode, I cannot change the aperture and it shows "`F - -`", which is an error.

I thought the lens is bad, so I bought another lens from a local store and it behaves the same. So I took my friend's D7000 and the 50mm lens works fine with it, so the lens is not bad. The other lenses I have are the kit lens 18-55 VR and 55-200 VR and they both work fine with my D3200, so its not that the camera is bad either, its just the combination of D3200 with 50mm and trying 2 new lenses with the same D3200, I am puzzled.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by this: "and trying 2 new different D3200". Did you try with one or two D3200?

Comment: I mean trying 2 new lenses with the same D3200

Comment: Update: Sent the camera to Nikon, they claimed the bayonet mount is the issue and asked for $160 to replace. On further discussing with them, they did the replacement for free under warranty. I received the camera and is now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cleaning the contacts of the body? It may be that the clearances are different between lenses, so the zooms apply a stronger force on the contacts.

It is obviously the body is at fault as two of the same lenses did not work. And there is a difference between the 50mm contact/lens mount and the zooms. Also, the 50mm works with the D7000 - so, your body is at fault most probably.

Another issue could be: D3200 firmware does not support the lens. Highly unlikely, but has happened. Check that you have the latest firmware on the D3200.

Comment: yup, have cleaned the lens and body contacts.
will check the firmware, if there is newer version.
i have the same feeling that the body is at fault, but the weirdness is that other lenses i tried with the body, they worked (18-55, 55-200 and now even 1.8/D )

Comment: just checked. the firmware is also latest C:1.01

Comment: @user3893309 The latest firmware is 1.03 ([link](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18784/~/d3200-firmware%3A-c%3A-1.03-upgrade))

Comment: @skuroda, thanks. It was only showing 1.01 from My Nikon page, will give it a try tonite and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried to upgrade to 1.03, still same issue. might have to send it to Nikon under warranty

Comment: I sent to Nikon and they are saying that the bayonet mount needs replacement and will not be covered in warranty (even thought its in 1 year) since it is possible due to some impact. I dont understand if the bayonet mount is faulty, how other senses are working. The cost of repairs is $160 :(

Comment: Thanks for reporting back the issue, sorry to hear that there is no easy way to repair it...